# В свойствах UWP проекта не открывается закладка Debug

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, отладка

[image: screen error]
Происходит именно в UWP проектах
Visual Studio 2015 и "15" Preview2

Comment: А что у вас за ссылка такая на COM объект? Если создаете новый проект, то не открывается также?

Comment: Это не у меня - это в VisualStudio

Comment: Судя по Реестру - это c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Phone Tools\CoreCon\12.0\Bin\ConManPS.dll  И да это на новом пустом проекте, но только в UWP. Консольный проект или WPF - все ОК